# Tengo un problema al usar PHP y MariaDB en IIS de Windows Server 2022

Tags: php, mariadb, iis, windows-server

he creado una página web en Xampp con html, css y php que realiza conexiones a una base de datos de phpMyAdmin, funciona perfectamente. El problema viene cuando traslado la página al IIS de Windows Server, tengo instalado el PHP y MariaDB pero cuando abro una página que debe conectar con la base de datos simplemente me muestra el error 500 de html. Si accedo a una página que solo tenga PHP y no realizo ninguna conexión a ninguna base de datos funciona perfectamente. A la base de datos puedo conectarme sin problemas desde la CMD o desde HeidySQL, imagino que el error estará en la conexión entre el PHP y la base de datos ya que en Xampp todo funcionaba perfectamente.
Les dejo el código de por ejemplo el login.php:

```
<?php
//Inicio de sesión
//session_start();

//Simulamos consulta a la BD indicando usuario y contraseña en otras variables
//$userBD="gonzalo";
//$passwBD="12345";

$servidor= "localhost";
$usuario= "gonzalo";
$clave= '12345';
$bd= "clases";

$conexion= mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $bd);
if (!$conexion)
{ 
    die("Error de conexión: " .mysql_connect_error());
}

$user=$_POST["usuario"];
$passwd=$_POST["passw"];

$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql = "SELECT usuario, contrasena, privilegio FROM usuario WHERE usuario= '".$user."' and contrasena = '".$passwd."'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$_SESSION["usuario"] = $user;
$_SESSION["password"] = $passwd;
$_SESSION["privilegio"] = $privilegio;

if ($nr == 1)
{ 
    header("Location: datos.php");
}
else if ($nr == 0)
{
    echo "Error al iniciar sesión";
}

//$conexion->close(); 

?>
```

Los usuarios que uso son los mismos que usé para acceder a MariaDB y funcionaron perfectamente.
También probé está página en un hosting online y funcionó sin problemas.

El log de acceso me da la siguiente información desde que inicio el servidor hasta que llego al error 500:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-06-06 14:15:13
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET / - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 304 0 0 1043
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET /index.css - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 304 0 0 21
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET /imagenes/NCC2020_InvV-e15871s26707967.png - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 304 0 0 43
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET /imagenes/clasesgente.jpg - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 304 0 0 42
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET /imagenes/personas.jpg - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 304 0 0 44
2023-06-06 14:15:13 192.168.1.64 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 404 0 2 48
2023-06-06 14:15:14 192.168.1.64 GET /login.html - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 304 0 0 13
2023-06-06 14:15:14 192.168.1.64 GET /login.css - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/login.html 304 0 0 53
2023-06-06 14:15:19 192.168.1.64 POST /login.php - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/login.html 500 0 0 1033
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-06-06 17:20:16
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-06-06 17:20:16 192.168.1.64 GET /favicon.ico - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/ 404 0 2 705
2023-06-06 17:20:16 192.168.1.64 GET /imagenes/Logotipo_de_la_Junta_de_Extremadura.svg.png - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/login.html 304 0 0 54
2023-06-06 17:20:21 192.168.1.64 POST /login.php - 80 - 192.168.1.47 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/114.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://192.168.1.64/login.html 500 0 0 1366
```

Por otro lado la carpeta de FailedReqLogFiles me aparece vacía.
El log de php ubicado en `C:\Windows\Temp` me muestra lo siguiente:

```
[06-Jun-2023 19:22:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login.php on line 14
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué dice el LOG de IIS? Normalmente los logs están en `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Comment: @jachguate He mirado lo que has dicho y diría que no aparece nada que me sirva de utilidad, te muestro el log creado desde que he iniciado el servidor hasta que accedí a login.php y me apareció el error: [enlace](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/909732223404638244/1115646431131344939/image.png)

Comment: Por favor, deja las partes esenciales del log como parte de la pregunta, y como texto, no como imagen. 2. Solo has visto, hasta ahora, el log de acceso, y ese nos confirma que se respondió con un status 500 (internal server error). Ahora faltaría ver el log de errores, que es el que potencialmente podría explicar cuál fue ese error interno que provocó el status 500.

Comment: @jachguate Acabo de actualizar la pregunta añadiendo el log que te envié por imagen, por otro lado la carpeta FailedReqLogFiles me aparece vacía, imagino que es hay donde debería esta el log de errores

Comment: Sin esa información, tendríamos que tener una bola de cristal para poder ayudarte. Quizás te falte habilitar los errores detallados: https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-detailed-iis-errors/

Comment: ¿Aparece algo relevante en `C:\Windows\Temp\php-x.y.z_errors.log`?

Comment: @jachguate He activado el log pero aunque reinicie el servicio y vuelva a acceder a la página del error la carpeta de FailedReqLogFiles sigue vacía [enlace](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/909732223404638244/1115706291311091732/image.png)

Comment: @aeportugal En esa carpeta no me aparece ningún log que contenga php en el nombre

Comment: Ok, el log está referenciado en IIS Manager -> [El Sitio] -> PHP Manager - PHP Settings - Error Log. Si no hay ningún error en la ubicación posiblemente sea porque aún no se ha producido alguno que haya creado el archivo.

Comment: @aeportugal He hecho lo que me has dicho y ahora si que me aparece el log de php, se lo dejo en una imagen. Me dice que hay un error en la línea 14 del archivo [enlace](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/909732223404638244/1115723803255898163/image.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el log de PHP aparece:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Usualmente IIS por defecto tiene todos (o casi todos) los módulos deshabilitado. Anda a IIS Manager -> PHP Manager al final en "*Enable o disable an extension*" y habilita:

```
php_mysqli.dll
php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Y de paso verifica si hacen falta otras extensiones como `mbstring` o `sqlite`. También en la parte de "*Manage all Settings*" revisa:

```
memory_limit -> 512M
post_max_size -> [ejem: 20M]
upload_max_size -> [ejem: 20M]
date.timezone -> [tu zona horaria]
```